# How can i specify which service use on a WSDL?

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I have to consume a WSDL that haves 2 Services (Service1 & Service2) and this ones has many functions.

What i need is: make a soap_call to the **functionX** on the Service1 and **functionY** on the Service2.

**This is how actually i make the connection:**

```
$options = [
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
    "connection_timeout" => 120,
    "trace" => 1,
    "exceptions" => 1,
];

$this->_objSoap = new SoapClient($this->_sURLService,$options);
```

**Execute a function:**

```
$result = (array)$this->_objSoap->__soapCall('functionX', $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke them?

```
$this->_objSoap = new SoapClient($this->_sURLService,$options);
$result_1 = $objSoap->function_x();
$result_2 = $objSoap->function_y();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I did that, but i receive an error from server => "[soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

For that is becouse i need mmmm like specify that the function x is on Service1.

Comment: make sure you're passing all required parameters, even if its just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I was making the call with Soap_Call, and that was the problem :/, now i make it on the obj.

**Connection:**

```
$options = [
    "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
    "connection_timeout" => 120,
    "trace" => 1,
    "exceptions" => 1,
]; 

$this->_objSoap = new SoapClient($this->_sURLService,$options);
```

**Before**

```
$result = (array)$this->_objSoap->Soap_Call(functionX,$params));
```

**Now**

```
$result = (array)$this->_objSoap->FunctionX($params);
```

The problem now is that i don't understand why using Soap_Call works on my others WSDL :/.